# Why i got error updated_at cannot be null activerecord rails 5.2 mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

This error happens in production 
using rails v 5.2
mysql v 5.7

i have no idea why this error happens

ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (Mysql2::Error: Column 'updated_at' cannot be null: UPDATE `conversations` SET `updated_at` = NULL WHERE `conversations`.`id` = 1)

i go no error in my local computer

Comment: the solution is simple dont't write NULL into that field or change the database to allow NULL on updated_at

Comment: i did't change to NULL, or change the db allow null on update_at

Comment: Then please add more context, may be  add logs, controller action etc.

Comment: You SET updated_at = NULL   so you set updated_at to NULL and your databse table don't have  NULL for the definition of updated_at. so **change it to NULL**

Comment: @Syafil In the error log, you must have got the line number that point you to the code which has caused this error. Please paste it here and then it would be easy to help.